ONNX I/O Binding
I need to bind tensor input and output using I/O Binding for ONNX runtime model. but i didn't get output. the output tensor return NULL pointer. I will attached the code below.
std::vector<Ort::Value> input_tensors;
std::vector<Ort::Value> output_tensors;
std::vector<const char*> input_node_names_c_str;
std::vector<const char*> output_node_names_c_str;
int64_t input_height = input_node_dims[0].at(2);
int64_t input_width = input_node_dims[0].at(3);

// // Pass gpu_graph_id to RunOptions through RunConfigs
Ort::RunOptions run_option;
// gpu_graph_id is optional if the session uses only one cuda graph
run_option.AddConfigEntry("gpu_graph_id", "1");

// Dimension expansion [CHW -> NCHW]
std::vector<int64_t> input_tensor_shape = {1, 3, input_height, input_width};
std::vector<int64_t> output_tensor_shape = {1, 300, 84};
size_t input_tensor_size = vector_product(input_tensor_shape);
size_t output_tensor_size = vector_product(output_tensor_shape);
std::vector<float> input_tensor_values(p_blob, p_blob + input_tensor_size);

Ort::IoBinding io_binding{session};
Ort::MemoryInfo memory_info = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtDeviceAllocator, OrtMemTypeCPU);

input_tensors.push_back(Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
        memory_info, input_tensor_values.data(), input_tensor_size,
        input_tensor_shape.data(), input_tensor_shape.size()
));

// Check if input and output node names are empty
for (const auto& inputNodeName : input_node_names) {
    if (std::string(inputNodeName).empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Empty input node name found." << std::endl;
    }
}

// format conversion
for (const auto& inputName : input_node_names) {
    input_node_names_c_str.push_back(inputName.c_str());
}

for (const auto& outputName : output_node_names) {
    output_node_names_c_str.push_back(outputName.c_str());
}

io_binding.BindInput(input_node_names_c_str[0], input_tensors[0]);

Ort::MemoryInfo output_mem_info{"Cuda", OrtDeviceAllocator, 0,
                                OrtMemTypeDefault};

cudaMalloc(&output_data_ptr, output_tensor_size * sizeof(float));
output_tensors.push_back(Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
    output_mem_info,  static_cast<float*>(output_data_ptr),output_tensor_size, 
    output_tensor_shape.data(),output_tensor_shape.size()));                            

io_binding.BindOutput(output_node_names_c_str[0],  output_tensors[0]);
session.Run(run_option, io_binding);

//Get output results
auto* rawOutput = output_tensors[0].GetTensorData<float>();
cout<<rawOutput<<endl; //suhail
cudaFree(output_data_ptr); //suhail
std::vector<int64_t> outputShape = output_tensors[0].GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetShape();
for(auto i:outputShape){cout<<i<<" ";} cout<<endl; //suhail
size_t count = output_tensors[0].GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetElementCount();
cout<<count<<endl; //suhail
std::vector<float> output(rawOutput, rawOutput + count);

i cross checked the input tensor data and shape as well as output tensor. but i am getting NULL pointer. How can i solve the issue. anyone have the experience with I/O Binding. please give me a tip for solving this.

try this
auto rawOutput = output_tensors.front().GetTensorMutableData<float>();

instead of
auto* rawOutput = output_tensors[0].GetTensorData<float>();


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
